# Viewing computers connected to my ISP

Tags: networking, subnet

If there are many computers connected to my ISP then doesn't that mean they are all on the same network?

If so, I should be able to see them. Why is it that this does not happen?

The question [Other computers behind isp cable](https://superuser.com/questions/268756/other-computers-behind-isp-cable) says that you can see all computers onle if they are on the same subnet mask. But I have observed that the subnet mask is `255.255.255.0` for almost all computers.

Or does this have another meaning?

Comment: Used to be (maybe 12 years ago) when I checked the "network" here at home, I'd see about a dozen computers in other homes in our neighborhood, several of which were "open kimono".  I was always tempted to print stuff on their printers, but never did it.  (Newer cable modems don't act this way, I'm pretty sure.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each modem contains its own router, which puts each household on a different subnet.

Your computer is connected to this subnet, and thus cannot see the ISP's network where other modems exist.

Comment: okay. For the purpose of experimentation lets say i want to view all the computers connected on my isp. Is this even possible.

Comment: No. Your computer is not actually on the ISP level network. Gaining access to that network would require ISP level access, which is unlikely these days without a court order or something.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: What if there is just a modem, not a router and the computer is connected to the modem directly? That (lack of router) is uncommon nowadays, but could happen.

Comment: @lupincho: There is still likely filtering of traffic between customers, implemented at the cable aggregator.  Only the ports the cable provider has opened to the outside world (commonly 22, almost certainly not 135-139) will be reachable, and they will be equally reachable from any computer on the 'Net whether the same ISP is used or not.

Answer (score -1):

Visit Your Router IP Address and Look for DHCP Client List 
Probably Router IP Address Is 192.168.1.1

default username and password may vary
try

admin, admin

admin, pass

admin, password

default, default

or try
http://google.com